# CakeDC Search Plugin with language

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakedc, croogo

```
public function search() {

    // start a standard search
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();

    // process the URL parameters
    $params = $this->Prg->parsedParams();

    // generate the Paginator conditions
    $conditions = $this->Book->parseCriteria($params);

    // add the conditions for paging
    $this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $conditions;

.....
}
```

I am using the search plugin with Croogo, it works perfectly fine. 
The url is like /rm/books/search?title=Harry+Potter when rm is my plugin
But when I switch the site to another language, it is redirected to the English version. So /rm/books/search?title=Harry+Potter instead of chi/rm/books/search?title=Harry+Potter

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have language defined as query param in your request object. You can pass the param name in allowedParams to commonProcess. If you dont have such param you will need overload commonProcess method and improve redirect build logic so it is support your multilangual routes.

Comment: At the end I need to hack the plugin core to fix this. The search plugin redirection didn't take the language routing into account.